# meanjs running fine in localhost but not in live server

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

I am using MeanJS[`meanjs0.4.2`] scaffolding for my web application. My application is running without any error in localhost, whereas in the live site i get the below shown error and empty page is rendered. I am not able to figure out where the error is?

Error - 
`Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
at angular.js:38 at Object.zc [as bootstrap] (angular.js:1646)`

My Config.js file where i include all my dependency injections

```
var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMessages', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils', 'ngFileUpload', 'angularFileUpload', 'ngMaterial', 'md-steppers', 'ngImgCrop', '720kb.datepicker','ui.select','material.svgAssetsCache'];
```

Also my bower.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "angular": "1.4.0",
    "angular-resource": "~1.3",
    "angular-animate": "1.4.0",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3",
    "angular-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "angular-ui-utils": "bower",
    "angular-ui-router": "1.0.5",
    "angular-file-upload": "1.1.5",
    "angular-messages": "1.4.0",
    "owasp-password-strength-test": "~1.3.0",
    "angular-material": "0.9.7",
    "angular-aria": "1.4.0",
    "ng-img-crop": "ngImgCrop#^0.3.2",
    "md-steppers": "^0.3.4",
    "angularjs-datepicker": "^2.1.23",
    "ng-file-upload": "^12.2.13",
    "svg-assets-cache.js": "svg-assets-cache#*"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.4.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.13",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems as though a service isn't being injected correctly on the live site.  Would you be able to show a little more code?

Comment: at a quick glance it would appear that you have injected a dependency into your module that isn't available to your production project. The mean.js generator should set up a separate set of dependencies for each environment - dev, test, production. Make sure you have the packages included in your production env and that you have run npm install

Comment: Thanks loulala. One of the files included in the production.js file was an unminified version. Changing it to the minified version resolved the issue.